# select students who choose both football and basketball

Tags: sql, group-by

I have a table `course` like this:

```
studentName  courseName

 Alen        basketball
 Alen        football
 Alen        tennis
 Bob         tennis
 Dean        football
 Charlie     football
 Charlie     basketball
```

I want to select student which choose **both** basketball and football.

Expected output:

```
studentName  courseName

 Alen        basketball
 Alen        football
 Alen        tennis
 Charlie     football
 Charlie     basketball
```

How can I do this efficiently?

I'm currently using this sql. It works fine but seems slow:

```
select * from course as ss1 where 
exists 
(select * from course as ss2 where ss2.studentName = ss1.studentName and ss2.courseName = 'basketball')
and exists
(select * from course as ss2 where ss2.studentName = ss1.studentName and ss2.courseName = 'football')
order by ss1.studentName desc
```

Comment: In your expected results, you have included tennis (third row) and in the question is it mentioned only football and basketball.

Comment: @user75ponic I want to select all records about the student who choose both basketball and football.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `EXIST` to fetch and compare intersecting data, you can try with `JOIN`.

A sample written in `sql-server` is below.

```
SELECT wholeStudents.*
FROM course wholeStudents
JOIN
  (SELECT DISTINCT StudentName
   FROM course
   WHERE CourseName IN ('basketball', 'football')
   GROUP BY StudentName 
   HAVING COUNT(1) =2) 
   AS disticnctStudents -- this table will only have a list of students selected both sports
ON (disticnctStudents.StudentName = wholeStudents.StudentName)
```

**Note** : It's as per the assumption that studentName is unique and a student can one one sport only once.

Answer (score 2):

```
select ss1.studentName, ss1.courseName c1, ss2.courseName c2 from course as ss1 
LEFT JOIN course as ss2 on ss1.studentName = ss2.studentName
where c1 != c2 and (c1 ='basketball' and c2 ='football')
```

Selecting student names

```
select ss1.studentName from course as ss1 
LEFT JOIN course as ss2 on ss1.studentName = ss2.studentName
where ss1.courseName != ss2.courseName and (ss1.courseName ='basketball' and 
ss2.courseName ='football')
```

Answer (score 0):

> SELECT * FROM course WHERE courseName = "basketball" OR courseName =
>   "football"

Long Live simplicity xD

Comment: Even if there are some DBMS accepting double quotes as string delimiters, it's better to use single quotes. And you query will also return students who only play basketball or football but not both.

Comment: right!
it has to be SELECT * FROM course WHERE courseName = 'basketball' AND courseName = 'football'

Comment: Which would result in an empty set as `courseName` cannot have two different values at a time.

Comment: And where is there a join in that query?

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2 simple queries and then find the intersection of both

```
SELECT studentName FROM course WHERE courseName = 'basketball'
INTERSECT
SELECT studentName FROM course WHERE courseName = 'football'
```

See this for postgres
http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-intersect/

Or this for Oracle
https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/intersect.php

Comment: Even if there are some DBMS accepting double quotes as string delimiters, it's better to use single quotes. Especially Postgres and Oracle, the ones you referred to, don't accept it. But your query won't work anyway, as the whole rows are unique and therefor the intersection empty. Instead of `SELECT * FROM ...` you probably wanted `SELECT studentName FROM ...`.

Comment: @stickybit You are right. I meant to say studentName. Modified the query. Thanks